# Which are the ways to access "Now Playing" in WatchOS 3?

Tags: music, apple-watch, watchos

I make use of the *Now Playing* view on Apple Watch to switch between songs playing on my iPhone's Soundcloud app.

[image]

However, I haven't yet found a satisfying (fast) way to access this view.

In WatchOS 3, the only way I know of is to click the "Dock" button on the side, and then swipe through the active apps to the location of *Now Playing*, and then click it. I think it's cumbersome.

I was hoping that there would be a complication to access this view, but for some reason Apple hasn't included one.

There is a *Music* complication, and once in that app, there is a "Now Playing" button. But strangely it doesn't seem to be linked to what's playing on my iPhone at the moment, even when I've set the *Source* to my iPhone. Perhaps this "Now Playing" function is reserved for Apple Music only.

So, my question is, what are the possible ways to access the *Now Playing* view? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of watchOS 4, you have a few options for accessing the Now Playing screen:

- Set the Dock Ordering setting for the Dock (Watch App on iPhone > Dock) to **Favorites** and choose the Now Playing "app" as one of your Favorites
- Add the Now Playing complication to a watch face (unfortunately, it's only available for Complication sections that are big enough to show the title of what's playing)

I actually included this in a roundup of [things I think should work with Siri on the Apple Watch but don't](https://medium.com/@gohnjanotis/siri-stuff-that-should-work-on-watchos-but-doesnt-476fbedd7fb0).

Comment: I'd also like to add that in the "Siri Watch Face", available in watchOS 4, provides a Now Playing "Data Source" card.

Answer (score 0):

Update the wake screen setting to show the last used app.

Go to General > Wake Screen > On Screen Wake show Last app on the iPhone App.

You can choose from options include session, 8 minute, 1 hour, always.

Now the watch always wakes up to the now playing screen.